# rails where and & query .count()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, where-clause

I am trying to count more than one attribute

```
<%= @user.cases.where(:finished => false)  and  @user.cases.where(:ready => false)  and  @user.cases.where(:ship => false)  and  @user.cases.where(:outsourced => false).all.count() %>
```

This is only count @user.cases.where(:outsourced => false) not all of them
Do you know the best way for it

Comment: Do you want the count of cases where all of the attributes are false or where any (i.e. at least one) of the attributes are false?

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and the Ruby 1.9 hash notation introduced in 2007 is fully supported. `ready: false` is sufficient here.

Comment: @HolgerJust the count of cases where all of the attributes are false

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```rb
@user.cases.where(finished: false, ready: false, ship: false, outsourced: false).count
```

Comment: it gives me 0 even if i change the false to true.

Comment: it's just count the last one not the sum of them all  outsourced: false

Comment: @nourza this will depend on the records on your database, which of course, we don't have access to, so we can't debug further. But 100% sure this is the query you were asking for: "count of cases where all of the attributes are false".